# Can I make a chrome extension to increase the time browser (client-side) cache gets stored in my browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension, browser-cache

The first time I open a site it take some time to open, but the next time I open the website in the same window, it takes less time. After researching, I found that this is because of Cache. But then I closed my window(also happens if on the same window but after a few hours), and then after it takes the more time again. Is there a way I can make a chrome extension that saves the browser cache, so that the next time I open the website, it takes less time to load?

Comment: No, Chrome ignores the changes made to cache-related HTTP headers from extensions. You can use an external HTTP proxy like Fiddler or Charles or even write one yourself in node.js.

Comment: is there any other data i can store from the website to decrease the loading time other than cache

Comment: Is there any way, i can make use of a code in node.js in my chrome extension fo working with the cache

Comment: I don't know. Look for examples. Maybe such a proxy already exists.